# Is there a geometric meaning of Phase portrait of Eigenvectors.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider a covariance matrix $A$ size $NXN$. It is a positive definite matrix and all its eigenvalues are non zero positive real numbers. In this case can we infer anything from the phase portrait of Eigenvectors? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of the phase portrait?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait :a wikipedia link

Comment: I understand the information in the link above. Could you explain how the phase portrait of your eigenvectors is generated? Perhaps with an example? In other words, how are trajectories being generated?

Comment: Thanks, but what is the phase portrait of an eigenvector? Can you provide a formulation of this concept in your post?

Comment: Yes, in Eigenvector case 'time' is not there so it is replaced by dimension. Although each of the dimension is independent I expected the phase portrait to have a form.